# proportion and ratio solving by m,n question

Tags: propositional-calculus, ratio

If $a/b = 1/3$ , $a/c=1/9$ and $a+b+c=26$ find $a,b,c$ 
I solved it by making in the first ratio 
$a=m$ 
$b=3m$ 
and in the second ratio 
$a=n$ 
$c=9n$ 
since $a=m , a=n$ then $m=n$ 
so $c=9m$ (since m=n) 
so we deduce that $a=m,b=3m,c=9m$ and we can solve it easily as equation 
but my teacher said it is wrong and I do not know why, can you explain ?, or is it right and my teacher is wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you wrote...though the bit about $m,n$ isn't necessary.  what final answer do you get?

Comment: The same answer as the way he solved it..

Comment: Well, I see nothing wrong with the method.  As I pointed out, you have unnecessary steps.  $\frac ab=\frac 13\implies b=3a$ immediately.  Similarly, $c=9a$.  So you can calculate along your lines more efficiently.  But what you did was ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your calculation, though it is a bit inefficient.  You don't need the $m,n$ for instance.  You could just write $$\frac ab=\frac 13\implies b=3a\quad \&\quad \frac ac=\frac 19\implies c=9a$$

Then conclude as $$a+b+c=26\implies a+3a+9a=13a=26\implies a=2, b=6, c=18$$

But you get there in the end.

Comment: this is the way he solved it with, thanks

Comment: Well, it's the same as your method.  You unnecessarily introduce statements like $a=m$, but, while unnecessary, such a step is not wrong.